# Magento 2 : PayPal onsite Payment method not working

Tags: paypal, magento2, payment-method

I want to use onsite PayPal method in magento 2 website.
I have configured this link : //prntscr.com/h0w1ew 
But in checkout page : //prntscr.com/h0w8wp 
When I click on Continue to Paypal button it shows error :**Not signed up for this tender type**

Question:
Why it's redirecting to PayPal? 
is there any tool for testing Pay flow details?

**Note**: I have created test user details from manager.paypal.com for PayFlow

LOG RESPONSE:
  `'response' => 
  array (
    'RESULT' => '25',
    'RESPMSG' => 'Not signed up for this tender type',
  ),`

Answer (score 0):

This error basically says the card number that you are trying from your site is not supported as per your payflow configuration.

In manager.paypal.com please go to "account administration"  tab, then click on "processor & merchant bank information" and click on "accepted tender types" and see the card types that you have enabled while registering.